# Hasone returns null in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have in my transaction mode:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Model\Interaction\Order');
}
```

I want to get the order with the transaction,

```
Transaction::where('id', 1)->with('order')->get();
```

but order is empty. In `transactions` table I have `order_id`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does this path `Model\Interaction\Order` correct ?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `transaction_id` in the `orders` table if you define relationship like that.

Since you have `order_id` in the `transactions` table, relationship should be [`belongsTo()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse):

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Model\Interaction\Order');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since order_id is on the interactions table, you should use belongsTo instead of hasOne

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that the child table i.e. the relation I thought had one actually had multiple entries with the same value. Eloquent doesn't select all the relations with matching IDs and slice 1 for you.
So, if you say

```
public function foo ()
 return $this->hasOne(Bar::class, 'this_class_id');
}
```

ensure that `Bar`'s table column `this_class_id` is indeed unique or else you'll stay getting null results